# Почему Блаженный Августин - "блаженный"?

Tags: этимология, орфоэпия

На юродивого этот философ явно не похож, и в качестве святого его признаёт, как западная, так и восточная церковь.

[image]
 *Православная икона Блаженного Августина.*

Comment: Спасибо, что предупреждаете об удалении и собственных комментариев.

Comment: [ссылка](http://russ.hashcode.ru/research/19095/%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B3%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD-%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B5%D1%82-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%8D%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%82) на исследование на данную тему.

Comment: Вот это верный ход!

Comment: >Вот это верный ход!  
   
Угу. Одобрямс )))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Блаженный - не только "юродивый", но и человек, которого Церковь считает спасённым и пребывающим на небесах, но в отношении которого не устанавливается общецерковное почитание, разрешено только местное. Часто это является предварительной ступенью перед канонизацией праведника.

http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9Блаже́нный (греч. μακάριος[1][2], лат. beatus[2][3], букв. счастливый) — эпитет, прилагаемый к христианским подвижникам, имеющий в различных христианских церквях разное значение. Сродни ст.-слав. блаженъ, от блажити — нарицать блаженным (делать благим, хорошим) наряду с исконнорусским бо́лого[4]. В широком смысле блаженный — всякий, кто лицезреет Бога на небесах (блаженное видение).

Comment: Блаженный, как местночтимый - это у католиков. И почему Августин с Иеронимом оказались среди блаженных это не объясняет. К моменту христианизации Руси, оба уже были святыми, почитаемыми всеми христианами. Хотя всё равно, спасибо.

Comment: Не совсем так.Ваш вопрос я поняла с точки зрения лингвистики, а не богословия. Если говорить, за что его назвали блаженным, то вот здесь подробно:http://orthodox-book.ru/index.php?catid=22:2011-09-03-19-35-34&id=294:2011-09-03-19-50-25&itemid=4&option=com_content&view=article